# Unable to start parity: database migration fails repeatedly

Tags: synchronization, parity, mac-osx, database

I am unable to start Parity, the database migration fails repeatedly. How in Parity on MacOS (1.4.5 already installed) do I eliminate this error so that my Parity will run?

Geth is fine but not running when this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and remove your blockchain.

```
rm -rf ~/.parity/906a34e69aec8c0d/*
```

Resync again with `--warp`, this only takes a few minutes.

```
parity --warp
```

Comment: .parity/906a34e69aec8c0d/v5.3-sec-overlayrecent/db: Directory not empty
parity --warp
Unknown flag: '--warp'
I have v1.4.5

Comment: parity --warp
Unknown flag: '--warp'

Comment: What's the output of `--version`?

Comment: ethcore/ethcore/parity 1.4.5 already installed
$ parity --warp
Unknown flag: '--warp'

Comment: It somehow seems it is not. Can you check `parity --version` if its the same binary linked?

Comment: ok right the linked version is 1.3.8-beta, so I need to unlink that parity but am unsure how to link the new version? ok unlinked 1.3.8-beta and reinstalling 1.4.5

Comment: $ brew install parity --beta
Updating Homebrew...
You can link formula with `brew link parity`
Warning: ethcore/ethcore/parity-1.4.5 already installed, it's just not linked
$ brew link parity
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/parity/1.3.8... 1 symlinks created
$ brew unlink parity
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/parity/1.3.8... 1 symlinks removed
$ brew link parity --beta
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/parity/1.3.8... 1 symlinks created
$ brew unlink parity
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/parity/1.3.8... 1 symlinks removed